# How to add PostSharp to team foundation server?

Tags: tfs, postsharp

I installed PostSharp on my project, but everybody has error when get solution, I asked [my problem  of postsharp technical support](http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/problems/1946-users-have-problem-on-build-after-get-project-in-team-foundation-server)  he said you must add packages to source control.
 Now I am not sure adding packages to source control or no? if I make a mistake again, all of users get error on his project,
I read the number of solutions and test one of them, so I caught error and I can not test they are right, please help me

Comment: Sorry, if the post on the support forum was not clear - I've only asked whether you commit the packages to source control to diagnose the problem. I certainly did not recommend you to do so.

Comment: The issue is caused by the missing file "PostSharp-Tools.exe", which normally should be installed from the PostSharp NuGet package.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here.

1. Use NuGet to manage your dependencies. This is by far the easiest option -- you can configure your solution to have NuGet package restore enabled, so when anyone builds your project, if the required dependencies aren't present, they'll be automatically downloaded.
2. Source control your dependencies in a folder somewhere in your project's structure (like \lib), and then reference those dependencies out of that folder. Ensure that the contents of that folder are in source control.

Comment: NuGet package restore was enable for they but when they were getting postsharp on build, they have error so I saw references and added postsharp.dll to that but not correctly.

Comment: Won't NuGet package restore always get the latest version of the packages?

Comment: @John Saunders, yes NuGet package always get latest version except you Specify version.

Comment: @HamidBahmanabady: My problem with that is, how do I know which version of the package I built with? It may not even be the version I want. I like to have control over which versions of packages I ship with.

Comment: You can set version for example (in package console manager): install-package postsharp -version 3.1.34

Comment: NuGet package restore will install the package versions specified in the packages.config file. So, it's the same versions that you add to your project during development.